# capitalize() first character in for loop from file

Tags: python, for-loop, intellij-idea, capitalize

In a python project I've been working on, I need to capitalize the first character of every 7 letter word from the file `/usr/share/dict/words` so I assumed `capitalize()` in a for loop would do the trick, but when I print out the results to see if it worked, not every word is capitalized. I don't know if the issue is the file input, loop, capitalize function, or something else. Here is my code...

```
def solve_1():
    file = open("/usr/share/dict/words", "r")
    for x in file:
        c = len(x) - 1
        x = x[0:c]
        # ^ to remove the /n at the end of every line
        if len(x) == 7:
            if x[0].isupper():
                pass
            else:
                x.capitalize()
```

So as you can see here, I opened the file, then looped through it, removing the end "/n" character, then tested each word to find only words of length 7, and if each word is capitalized pass, but if not then cap it.

My results end up looking like this every time...[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDWWp.png)

I've been stuck on this for quite a while, if anyone could help, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: You should use `strip()` for newline removal. `capitalize()` also efficiently handles strings which are already capitalized, so you don't need to test.

Comment: okay thanks for the tip

Comment: I can't see anything immediately wrong with the 'rest' of your code - please update your code using these builtin functions and see if that  fixes it - if not post the modified code for review.

Comment: You're ignoring the return value of `capitalize()`

Comment: Oh! So I need to set x = x.capitalize()

Comment: Yes, that did the trick thank you, everyone!

Comment: Also, `c = len(x) - 1; x = x[0:c]` is an overly complicated and error prone way of getting rid of the endline character. First, could simplify in `x = x[:-1]`. But that would still be a problem if there is no endline character. `x = x.strip()` will get rid of any leading or trailing endline characters and still work if there are none. If you just want to remove the trailing ones, use `rstrip()`.

Comment: You're not printing anything, how are you getting any output?